# Load Last Viewed Page in WebView

Tags: java, android, webview

I have a WebView that loads a specific URL. If the user navigates away from the web view to another section of the app or if they leave the app, I want the web view to load the last page they were on when they navigated away from it. In iOS I was able to do this by getting the current URL and saving it to NSUserDefaults but I'm not sure how to accomplish this on Android.

Here is my code.

```
public class MyKYFB extends Fragment {

    private WebView web;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    private String url;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_kyfb, null);

        url = "https://my.kyfb.com";

        web = (WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.kyfb_web);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar)rootView.findViewById(R.id.prgPageLoading);

        web.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        web.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        web.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        web.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        web.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);

        web.loadUrl(url);

        web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView webView, int progress) {
                getActivity().setProgress(progress * 100);
                progressBar.setProgress(progress);
            }
        });

        web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(web, url, favicon);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(web, url);
                progressBar.setProgress(0);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
            {
                if(url.endsWith(".mp4") || url.endsWith(".3gp") || url.endsWith(".avi") || url.endsWith(".flv")){
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(i); //warning no error handling will cause force close if no media player on phone.
                    return true;
                }

                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to open the same url when user reopen your app, you have to save it somewhere. An easy way to do this is to use SharePreferences :

**When user leave the app/WebView :**

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putString(SP_LAST_WEBVIEW_URL), getString(yourWebView.getUrl());
editor.commit();
```

Put this at the begining of your current class : `private static final String SP_LAST_WEBVIEW_URL = "com.app.yourapp.LASTWEBVIEWURL";`

**To load the saved url** : replace `web.loadUrl(url);` by :

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String savedUrl = getResources().getString(SP_LAST_WEBVIEW_URL);
web.loadUrl(savedUrl);
```

Comment: It's not really a matter of needing to go back. I'm wanting the web view to load to the last page they were on before leaving the web view. The way it currently works is that it loads the same page every time the user chooses to go to the web view.

Answer (score 1):

In onPageFinished, store the URL to system preferences (or somewhere else).

Then, in onCreateView, retrieve this value, and if not null, use it as the url to load.